# Latex in Ubuntu - alternative to Adobe Acrobat

Tags: pdf, ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu and write in latex. I have to create a pdf-file with a password protection. The resulting file must be compatible to adobe acrobat/windows.
That means that the person I give the file should be able to open it using the adobe acrobat on windows machine.
Is there any way of doing so?

Comment: Normally there is no problem.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to TeX.sx. This is not really on topic for this site. However, there is a version of Adobe reader for linux available, although not directly linked from the adobe website, but from their ftp server: ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/unix/9.x/9.5.5/enu/

Comment: Welcome! As Bernard says, this should work. Has the recipient experienced difficulties? How did you add the password exactly? Do note that this kind of protection is not worth much. It is more a way of telling people you'd like them to respect your request than of enforcing it.

Comment: @ArTourter I don't think that's the question. The question is about a PDF prepared using other software on Ubuntu, with the password added on Ubuntu and will that then work OK in acroread on Windows. acroread will not be any use here on Ubuntu because it will not allow the addition of the password. But that's fine. It doesn't need to and the question isn't asking for that, I don't think.

Comment: @cfr I was mainly suggesting this as a way to test the pdf. If whatever is done on it works in adobe reader on Linux, it should work on windows. I have used pdftk for that sort of things and it works fine.

Comment: @ArTourter Oh, I see. Yes, that's very true.

Answer (score 0):

[pdfcrypt](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfcrypt) allows you to set encryption options, including passwords, when producing PDF. These should work fine with PDF viewers which support these features of PDF, including Adobe's viewers and regardless of platform.

Note, however, that the security this kind of protection provides is very weak. It it more akin to a forceful request than an enforcement mechanism.